# Running make -j$(nproc) or make modules -j$(nproc)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, real-time, rtos

I am following [this](https://github.com/UNIBO-GRABLab/cable_robot/wiki/Installation). To run

```
make -j$(nproc)
make modules -j$(nproc)
```

I know that make is running [jobs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/make)
**Are the jobs supposed to run for hours?** (I got impatient and interrupted.)

```
make -j$(nproc)
```

Comment: What hardware are you running on? Does the build actually start and show any output in the console?

Comment: Intel core i3 sandybridge desktop 64 bit. Yes the build is showing outputs and it is still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can run for hours, it all depends on your hardware and the quantity of code you're trying to compile.

Don't be impatient, just wait, or compile this on a better machine with a better CPU!